# Why are UNIX shells like this and how can I work around it?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

One of the things I've noticed about BASH and other UNIX shells is that, by default and when used in typical ways, they spawn subshells for almost everything.

e.g.

```
foo=$(grep "someword" /path/to/somefile | awk '{print $3}')
```

would spawn two new sessions of bash just to load some text into a variable.

a) Why do shells do this? If a command line program operates on file descriptors, one shouldn't need to spawn a new non-interactive shell session just to feed it a descriptor, right?

b) How can I best work around this, when loading command output into variables? I know that in bash you can use:

```
read -r -d '' < <(...)
```

to set a variable from a command without using a subshell, but this rather cumbersome, and I'm looking for better (and more portable) methods. (Likewise it would be cool if anyone knew general alternatives to pipes and command substitution that did *not* involve subshells.)

NB: I know "user Perl/Python/Ruby" is probably the "correct" solution, but those all tend to need a lot of boilerplate code to do file manipulation, external command invocation, etc.

Edit: thanks for the answers below, however this still does not explain why process substitution must fork new shells *even for builtin commands*:

```
$ builtin echo $(builtin echo $(builtin echo $BASH_SUBSHELL))
2
```

Comment: See [here](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/What_is_a_Subshell%3F).  Try using `exec`.

Comment: That doesn't work the way you say it does. Using 'exec' in a command substitution just forks a shell that immediately exits, incurring the full overhead and other issues of spawning a subshell; you can verify this by '/usr/bin/echo'ing $BASH_SUBSHELL within such an invocation.

Comment: See Vinc17's answer below.  An implicit exec vs something like an explicit exec: `exec 2>/dev/null`

Comment: `foo=$(grep ... | awk)` spawns one subshell, for the command substitution.

Comment: Forking helps to isolate scope, so (for example) if one of those programs `cd` for whatever reason then it won't affect the current directory of the calling script.  Having just spent an hour debugging a suite of Windows CMD scripts, I would be happy to suffer a few microseconds of lag for forking if it meant that scope was protected from child scripts.

Comment: That being said, I *think* backticks don't create a subshell implicitly, although obviously a pipe within the backticks would create a subshell.

Comment: You can spare one process: `foo=$(awk '/someword/ {print $3}' /path/to/somefile)`...

Comment: If you really hate the idea of commands be executed in subshells, you could try using something like busybox. But, I'd not worry about optimizing the way the shells do this unless you have performance numbers that show that this is a constraining bottleneck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To execute a command such as `grep` or `awk`, the shell must fork, which means that you get a subshell. The only exceptions are when the command is a builtin or when the command is the last command. But this latter case is just an optimization done by some shells and cannot be done under some conditions that might change the behavior (e.g. existing traps); basically this is an implicit `exec`. Hence your two subshells for

```
foo=$(grep "someword" /path/to/somefile | awk '{print $3}')
```

To avoid subshells, there are various workarounds, and you need to find them depending on the context...

Comment: Right, because of the fork/exec system of process spawning on UNIX. I had forgotten that UNIX does not have a single syscall to spawn a new process... D'oh!

Answer (score 3):

*Focussing on a):*

Executing the command

```
foo=$(echo bar)
```

starts a subshell, because the command is using a command substitution, which implies a subshell as the environment that is used.

The command **explicitly runs a subshell**, as simple as that.
And that does not change if you nest it.

Now, after the question "Why is the shell doing that" is answered:
**Why are you asking that?**

It's an interesting topic, but I do not fully see what you are aiming at;
Some wild guesses:

- Proposing an optimizing bash implementation?
- Reducing count of forks? For performance reasons? For some kind of aesthetic reasons?   It's the fastest way to provide a separate environment, including address space - a   process.
- Changing the shell's syntax? To reach exactly what goal?

If you like, some add details to the question, an leave me a comment.

---

From [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html)

```
COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT
       [ ... ]

       Command substitution, commands grouped with  parentheses,  and  asyn‐
       chronous  commands  are  invoked  in a subshell environment that is a
       duplicate of the shell environment, except that traps caught  by  the
       shell  are reset to the values that the shell inherited from its par‐
       ent at invocation.  Builtin commands that are invoked as  part  of  a
       pipeline  are  also executed in a subshell environment.  Changes made
       to the subshell environment cannot affect the shell's execution envi‐
       ronment.

       [ ... ]
```